# SQL Server 2008 - Why can't I use WHERE on query from select count(*) as

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which works as it should do:

```
Select 
    WB.BinNumber, WB.ID, 
    (select count(*) 
     from WMS_LocationBalance 
     where BinID = WB.ID) AS BinCount 
from 
    WMS_WarehouseBin WB
ORDER BY 
    BinCount
```

But when adding `WHERE BinCount = 0` the query doesn't run, because `BinCount` is an invalid column name.

Why is it I can `order by BinCount` but I can't use in `WHERE`?

Also how can I resolve this?

```
Select 
    WB.BinNumber, 
    WB.ID, 
    (select count(*) 
     from Location 
     where BinID = WB.ID) AS BinCount 
from 
    WarehouseBin WB
WHERE 
    BinCount = 0
ORDER BY 
    BinCount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. You cannot use `Alias name` in `Where clause` because `WHERE clause` is processed before the `SELECT clause(*)`, and so the aliases aren't available try using a`derived table` then use the alias name in where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT WB.BinNumber,
               WB.ID,
               (SELECT Count(*)
                FROM   Location
                WHERE  BinID = WB.ID) AS BinCount
        FROM   WarehouseBin WB) A
WHERE  A.BinCount = 0
ORDER  BY a.BinCount
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` reads from the source table, and is part of the query - therein lies your issue

`ORDER BY` can  be used on the field, as `ORDER BY` is used after the data has been fetched - it works with the data AFTER it's been cached.

Hope this explains your issue.

--

For a resolution,

I'd recommend inserting the data into a "hash table", or even a temp table (using @ variables), then ordering it using a select. Or, use a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend rewriting the query with a GROUP BY clause instead of using a subquery (since you dont want 0's, which GROUP BY automatically eliminates). Much neater.

```
SELECT   WB.BinNumber, WB.ID, COUNT(*) AS BinCount
FROM     WMS_WarehouseBin WB INNER JOIN WMS_LocationBalance L ON WB.ID = L.BinID
GROUP BY WB.BinNumber, WB.ID
ORDER BY BinCount
```